# Python: get first elements from tuple of strings

Tags: python, string, list, tuples, slice

I have the following query: is it possible to get tuple of first symbols for every string in tuple by slice?
I've tried the following code:

```
t = ("aaa", "aab", "abc", "aba", "bcc")
print(t[:][0])
```

and I got "aaa". What I want is ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'].
Sure it can be done by generator:

```
letters = (x[0] for x in t)
```

But is it possible to do by slices?
Thank you.

Comment: You should use list comprehension: `letters = [x[0] for x in t]`.

Comment: I don't see how you can do this with slices alone... but I would be interested if it is possible...

Comment: Can't find a better slice: `[x[0:1] for x in t]`.

Comment: @Austin `[x[:1] for x in t]` is even better.

Comment: @DYZ: Depends on how you see it; one 0 but not including 1 and other all before 1. :)

Comment: Performance-wise, [:1] is 10% faster than [0:1].

Answer (score 2):

The following code does not explicitly use slicing, but it is very efficient:

```
letters = next(zip(*t))
letters
#('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b')
```

This method is 25% faster than the list comprehension with selection (`[0]`) and 48% faster than the list comprehension with slicing (`[:1]`).

Answer (score 2):

The classic solution is to use a list comprehension. An alternative, functional, method is to use `operator.itemgetter`.

But you can get closer to vectorised functionality via 3rd party NumPy. Here you should see large performance improvements. The slicing is trivial; the cost is largely from conversion to a NumPy array.

The NumPy solution assumes your strings are of the same length and you are comfortable with having your output as an array rather than a list:

```
res = np.array(t).view('<U1')[::len(t[0])]
```

Some performance benchmarking:

```
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter

t = ("aaa", "aab", "abc", "aba", "bcc")
t = t*500000
t_arr = np.array(t)

def comp(tup):
    return [x[0] for x in tup]

def func(tup):
    return list(map(itemgetter(0), tup))

def nump(tup):
    return np.array(tup).view('<U1')[::len(tup[0])]

def nump2(arr):
    return arr.view('<U1')[::len(arr[0])]

def dyz(tup):
    letters, *_ = zip(*tup)
    return letters

def dyz2(tup):
    return next(zip(*tup))

%timeit comp(t)       # 276 ms per loop
%timeit func(t)       # 338 ms per loop
%timeit nump(t)       # 174 ms per loop
%timeit nump2(t_arr)  # 2.86 µs per loop
%timeit dyz(t)        # 351 ms per loop
%timeit dyz2(t)       # 245 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible because a Slice can't return more than one String.
You need to loop on your Tuple : [x[0] for i in t].